# How to view the data size of a database in HybridDB for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am using **HybridDB for PostgreSQL** in Alibaba Cloud ECS.

My Question is:
How can I view the data size of a table and a database in HybridDB for PostgreSQL

I appreciate any assistance with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that the table schema is  and the table name is .

Run the following command to query the **total size of a table** (unit: MB, including the table index and data):

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('<schemaname>.<tablename>'));
```

Run the following command to query the **data size of a table** (unit: MB, excluding the index):

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size('<schemaname>.<tablename>'));
```

Run the following command to query the **total size of all the partitions** in a partition table (unit: MB, including the table index and data):

```
select schemaname,tablename,round(sum(pg_total_relation_size(schemaname || '.' || partitiontablename))/1024/1024) "MB" from pg_partitions where schemaname='<schemaname>' and tablename='<tablename>' group by 1,2;
```

Run the following command to query the **total size of all the tables under a schema** (unit: MB, including the index and data):

```
select schemaname ,round(sum(pg_total_relation_size(schemaname||'.'||tablename))/1024/1024) "Size_MB" from pg_tables where schemaname='<schemaname>' group by 1;
```

Run the following command to query **the size of each database** (unit: MB):

select datname,pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(datname)) from pg_database;

You can get more help from [this link](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/faq-detail/50319.htm)